# RX GroupByUntil with sliding Until

Tags: system.reactive

I'm using GroupByUntil to group messages from MSMQ that have specific property values which is working wonderfully.  I'm using this code.

```
observable.GroupByUntil(
    message => message.Source,
    message => message.Body,
    message => Observable.Timer(new TimeSpan(0,0,5)) //I thought this was sliding expiration
).Subscribe(HandleGroup);
```

I mistakenly thought that each time a new message arrived for a given group, that group's durationSelector would restart, essentially waiting for the duration to pass with no new messages before ending the group.  I realize that is not the case, and that the durationSelector is going to continue to count down no matter what.  What is the best way to achieve a sliding durationSelector for each group as it's being grouped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Switch`](http://www.introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/12_CombiningSequences.html#Switch) is your friend.

```
observable.GroupByUntil(
    message => message.Source,
    message => message.Body,
    group => group
        .Select(message => Observable.Timer(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5)))
        .Switch() 
).Subscribe(HandleGroup);
```

Explanation:

- For each message, create a timer that fires once after 5 seconds
- If another message comes along within the same group, drop the old timer, and switch to the new one.

Comment: "Switch - convert an Observable that emits Observables into a single Observable that emits the items emitted by the most-recently-emitted of those Observables" hahahah, what!?.  Would have never deciphered that.

Comment: Text explanations of Observable operators normally fall short. Marble diagrams are much more valuable.